# ListView onClick update clears the list

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, onclick, onitemclicklistener

I have the following code that's supposed to remove the item that is clicked on:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
    String itemValue = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
    email_addresses.remove(position);

    String size = Integer.toString(email_addresses.size());
    Log.d("Size: ", size);

    //listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.email_list);
    //ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, email_addresses);
    //listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(mainAppContext, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, email_addresses);
    ((ListView)parent).setAdapter(adapter);
    parent.refreshDrawableState();
}
```

When I click on an item the list is cleared and nothing is displayed. The size is the correct value and the list can be rebuilt but I am unable to get this code to work.
Thank you

Comment: delete last 3 lines. Instead try calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` . `adapter` is defined outside of `setOnItemClickListener`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating a whole new Adapter each time, have you thought about simply making your Adapter a member variable and calling [notifyDataSetChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged())?

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(mainAppContext, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, email_addresses);
((ListView)parent).setAdapter(adapter);
```

Becomes:

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 1):

Define your list and adapter as instant variables and  also You have to notify the adapter in order to make the deletion affect , 
Try this ,

```
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            email_addresses.remove(position);
            adapter .notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```